# Window Stacking on OS X

Tags: macos, mac

I have a MBP with retina display and run OS X Mavericks.

My problem:  imagine I have two applications open

- a document viewer sized half-screen (filling the left side of the screen).  Call this "Window A".
- an editor with two windows: one is full-screen because it contains really long lines (Window B) and the other is half-screen (filling the right side of the screen) (Window C).

I want to read the document and take notes on it in the editor, but when I give focus to half-screen-sized editor window, the document reader is hidden behind the full-screen-sized editor window.

Is there a way to make the stacking order independent of the app?

That is, when Window A is focused, I can still see Window C.  When Window C is focused, Window A is behind Window B.  I want to be able to view Window A and C at the same time even in Window C is receiving keyboard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not suit your needs, but what about adding a new space and put your fullscreen window over there. It's very fast to switch the spaces using the multitouch abilities of your trackpad. I use this feature a lot when working on multiple documents.

Comment: Thanks, @Andy.  I hadn't considered this.  I'm pretty new to OS X and haven't used spaces at all.  That seems like a pretty good work-around to me.

I'd like to see if there are other options, but if I don't see any, I'll accept your answer as "the one" and move on. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Another solution is using mission control in general just to put that window in front what you need (Mission Control is the new name of spaces since I think 10.7, just to clarify). If I remember that right it's accessed by a 3 finger swap upwards on the trackpad per default. Depending on what Apps you're using they might also have a fullscreen mode to enable in top right corner, which gives them an own desktop automatically). Otherwise you can make extra spaces/desktops in Mission Control by holding alt and adding them in the top right corner.